qgis2map not showing the assigned symbology
I have a basic heatmap created from point vector, but when I use qgis2web to send to my supervisor, the radius of the points is altered. This is my first time using this plugin, and cannot find similar issues. Cheers, See below



The symbology supported by qgis2web is described in the documentation at this address https://qgis2web.github.io/qgis2web/ If you can upload your QGIS project somewhere and enter the link here, I can watch it.
